# Add elements to div and then fade it in using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I want to delete a div with id=mainContainer.

I have removed it then fade it out:

```
$("#mainContainer").fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Then I created new div with same id:

```
var newPageDiv = $("<div>", {id: "mainContainer"});
```

How can I add :

```
 <a href="#">
   <img class="homeImage" src="images/home.jpg" border="0">
 </a>
```

and :

```
<a class="Next" onclick="tabs.clickNext();"
   <p>Next</p>
</a>
```

to "newPageDiv " and then show(fadeIn) "newPageDiv" using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fadeout I would just remove the content in the mainContainer div.

```
$("#mainContainer").fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).html(); });
```

Then add back your new HTML and fadein.

```
$("#mainContainer").fadeIn(300, function () {
            var str = '<a href="#"><img class="homeImage" src="images/home.jpg" border="0"></a><a class="Next" onclick="tabs.clickNext();"<p>Next</p></a>';
             $(this).html(str);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

How to add HTML to element in jQuery:

```
$('#mydiv').html('<div>this will be #mydiv innerHTML</div>');
```

Then

```
$("#mydiv").fadeIn(300);
```

If you're working a lot with HTML in jQuery you might be interested in [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
var newPageDiv = $("<div id='mainContainer'>" +
"<a href='#'><img class='homeImage' src='images/home.jpg' border='0'></a>" +
"<a class='Next' onclick='tabs.clickNext();'><p>Next</p></a>" +
"</div>");

newPageDiv.fadeIn(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have a container div that you can then append this other div to. I have given you the code plus a JSFiddle link.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Append your new div to the container div
$(".container").append("<div id='mainContent'></div>");
// Append the image to the mainContent div
$("#mainContent").append("<a href='#'><img src='http://www.mytabletbooksqa.com/ProductImages/test1.gif' /></a>");
```

[Fiddle for your example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemahony/MrMjg/1/)